# Looping through a SharePoint List with Power Query

Tags: sharepoint-2013, powerquery

we have a SharePoint List, in the following called the Overview List with approx. 1000 projects. 
Simplified, the Overview List contains only 2 columns - the project name and the link to the projects SharePoint sub-site.

Each project has it´s own SharePoint sub-site containing several lists e.g.

```
financial details
time details
administration details
etc.
```

Now I want to establish a query in Power Query M Language, which

- loops through each project in the Overview list,

  - reads the URL´s of the Projects subsite
  - open e.g. the financial details list in this project´s subsite
  - reads the columns of the financial data list
  - populates the result-list with the project name and all details
- until the end of the Overview List

As a new user in this forum, I am not allowed to post images. However I hope that the description is sufficient to catch the idea.

Any idea how this could be solved with Power Query is highly appreciated and would be a great help in dealing with SharePoint data.

Thanks in advance for your contributions and

Best regards

Frank Radewagen

Comment: Have you tried to create a query that returns all the data you want from a given subsite? If you can accomplish that, then all you need to do is convert that query into a function that takes a subsite URL as a parameter. Then on your query that has the list of subsites, add a column that runs this function on the subsite column and it will return a list of tables with all your data that you can combine.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That sounds almost too good. I will give it a try by tomorrow. Enjoy your day.